# The Search Button is not working in my Code

Tags: html, css

The Search Button is not working in my Search Form. I make the Search form only using html and pure CSS to practice that JS is important or not to use in Search form with Drop Down Filter!. Do i need to use some JS code or it is Possible to make it work? I like to share my Knowledge and anyone can use my Code.

Regards: Xan

```css
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
    #DIV_1 {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            width: 500px;
            perspective-origin: 250px 20px;
            transform-origin: 250px 20px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
            margin: 2px 0px 0px;
        }/*#DIV_1*/
        
        #DIV_1:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_1:after*/
        
        #DIV_1:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_1:before*/
        
        #DIV_2 {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            left: 0px;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            min-height: 1px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 405px;
            perspective-origin: 202.5px 20px;
            transform-origin: 202.5px 20px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_2*/
        
        #DIV_2:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_2:after*/
        
        #DIV_2:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_2:before*/
        
        #DIV_3 {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: table;
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            left: 0px;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 352px;
            perspective-origin: 250px 20px;
            transform-origin: 250px 20px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_3*/
        
        #DIV_3:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_3:after*/
        
        #DIV_3:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_3:before*/
        
        #DIV_4 {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            float: left;
            height: 38px;
            left: 0px;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 149.391px;
            perspective-origin: 74.6875px 19px;
            transform-origin: 74.6953px 19px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_4*/
        
        #DIV_4:after {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            content: '""';
            display: block;
            height: 22px;
            left: 168.391px;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -20px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 10px;
            width: 1px;
            perspective-origin: 0.5px 11px;
            transform-origin: 0.5px 11px;
            background: rgb(233, 233, 233) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_4:after*/
        
        #DIV_4:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#DIV_4:before*/
        
        #SELECT_5 {
            background-position: 150px 18px;
            bottom: 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 38px;
            left: 0px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 137px;
            perspective-origin: 68.5px 19px;
            transform-origin: 68.5px 19px;
            background: rgb(255, 255, 255) url("http://opencart.templatemela.com/OPC10/OPC100235/OPC4/catalog/view/theme/OPC100235_4/image/megnor/select-arrow-down.gif") no-repeat scroll 150px 18px / auto padding-box border-box;
            border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
            padding: 8px 15px;
        }/*#SELECT_5*/
        
        #SELECT_5:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#SELECT_5:after*/
        
        #SELECT_5:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#SELECT_5:before*/
        
        #OPTION_6, #OPTION_7, #OPTION_9, #OPTION_11, #OPTION_13, #OPTION_15, #OPTION_17, #OPTION_19, #OPTION_21, #OPTION_23, #OPTION_25, #OPTION_27, #OPTION_29, #OPTION_31, #OPTION_33, #OPTION_35, #OPTION_37, #OPTION_39, #OPTION_41, #OPTION_43 {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            min-height: 14.4px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_6, #OPTION_7, #OPTION_9, #OPTION_11, #OPTION_13, #OPTION_15, #OPTION_17, #OPTION_19, #OPTION_21, #OPTION_23, #OPTION_25, #OPTION_27, #OPTION_29, #OPTION_31, #OPTION_33, #OPTION_35, #OPTION_37, #OPTION_39, #OPTION_41, #OPTION_43*/
        
        #OPTION_6:after, #OPTION_7:after, #OPTION_9:after, #OPTION_11:after, #OPTION_13:after, #OPTION_15:after, #OPTION_17:after, #OPTION_19:after, #OPTION_21:after, #OPTION_23:after, #OPTION_25:after, #OPTION_27:after, #OPTION_29:after, #OPTION_31:after, #OPTION_33:after, #OPTION_35:after, #OPTION_37:after, #OPTION_39:after, #OPTION_41:after, #OPTION_43:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_6:after, #OPTION_7:after, #OPTION_9:after, #OPTION_11:after, #OPTION_13:after, #OPTION_15:after, #OPTION_17:after, #OPTION_19:after, #OPTION_21:after, #OPTION_23:after, #OPTION_25:after, #OPTION_27:after, #OPTION_29:after, #OPTION_31:after, #OPTION_33:after, #OPTION_35:after, #OPTION_37:after, #OPTION_39:after, #OPTION_41:after, #OPTION_43:after*/
        
        #OPTION_6:before, #OPTION_7:before, #OPTION_9:before, #OPTION_11:before, #OPTION_13:before, #OPTION_15:before, #OPTION_17:before, #OPTION_19:before, #OPTION_21:before, #OPTION_23:before, #OPTION_25:before, #OPTION_27:before, #OPTION_29:before, #OPTION_31:before, #OPTION_33:before, #OPTION_35:before, #OPTION_37:before, #OPTION_39:before, #OPTION_41:before, #OPTION_43:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_6:before, #OPTION_7:before, #OPTION_9:before, #OPTION_11:before, #OPTION_13:before, #OPTION_15:before, #OPTION_17:before, #OPTION_19:before, #OPTION_21:before, #OPTION_23:before, #OPTION_25:before, #OPTION_27:before, #OPTION_29:before, #OPTION_31:before, #OPTION_33:before, #OPTION_35:before, #OPTION_37:before, #OPTION_39:before, #OPTION_41:before, #OPTION_43:before*/
        
        #OPTION_8, #OPTION_10, #OPTION_14, #OPTION_18, #OPTION_22, #OPTION_26, #OPTION_30, #OPTION_34, #OPTION_38, #OPTION_42 {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            min-height: 14.4px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_8, #OPTION_10, #OPTION_14, #OPTION_18, #OPTION_22, #OPTION_26, #OPTION_30, #OPTION_34, #OPTION_38, #OPTION_42*/
        
        #OPTION_8:after, #OPTION_10:after, #OPTION_14:after, #OPTION_18:after, #OPTION_22:after, #OPTION_26:after, #OPTION_30:after, #OPTION_34:after, #OPTION_38:after, #OPTION_42:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_8:after, #OPTION_10:after, #OPTION_14:after, #OPTION_18:after, #OPTION_22:after, #OPTION_26:after, #OPTION_30:after, #OPTION_34:after, #OPTION_38:after, #OPTION_42:after*/
        
        #OPTION_8:before, #OPTION_10:before, #OPTION_14:before, #OPTION_18:before, #OPTION_22:before, #OPTION_26:before, #OPTION_30:before, #OPTION_34:before, #OPTION_38:before, #OPTION_42:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_8:before, #OPTION_10:before, #OPTION_14:before, #OPTION_18:before, #OPTION_22:before, #OPTION_26:before, #OPTION_30:before, #OPTION_34:before, #OPTION_38:before, #OPTION_42:before*/
        
        #OPTION_12, #OPTION_16, #OPTION_24, #OPTION_32, #OPTION_40 {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            min-height: 14.4px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_12, #OPTION_16, #OPTION_24, #OPTION_32, #OPTION_40*/
        
        #OPTION_12:after, #OPTION_16:after, #OPTION_24:after, #OPTION_32:after, #OPTION_40:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_12:after, #OPTION_16:after, #OPTION_24:after, #OPTION_32:after, #OPTION_40:after*/
        
        #OPTION_12:before, #OPTION_16:before, #OPTION_24:before, #OPTION_32:before, #OPTION_40:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_12:before, #OPTION_16:before, #OPTION_24:before, #OPTION_32:before, #OPTION_40:before*/
        
        #OPTION_20, #OPTION_28 {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            min-height: 14.4px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_20, #OPTION_28*/
        
        #OPTION_20:after, #OPTION_28:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_20:after, #OPTION_28:after*/
        
        #OPTION_20:before, #OPTION_28:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_20:before, #OPTION_28:before*/
        
        #OPTION_36 {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            min-height: 14.4px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_36*/
        
        #OPTION_36:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_36:after*/
        
        #OPTION_36:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#OPTION_36:before*/
        
        #INPUT_44 {
            color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            display: block;
            float: left;
            height: 38px;
            text-decoration: none solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            width: 348.594px;
            column-rule-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            perspective-origin: 174.297px 19px;
            transform-origin: 174.297px 19px;
            caret-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            border: 0px none rgb(85, 85, 85);
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 15.96px Poppins, sans-serif;
            outline: rgb(85, 85, 85) none 0px;
            padding: 10px 30px;
        }/*#INPUT_44*/
        
        #INPUT_44:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            text-decoration: none solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            column-rule-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            caret-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            border: 0px none rgb(85, 85, 85);
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 15.96px Poppins, sans-serif;
            outline: rgb(85, 85, 85) none 0px;
        }/*#INPUT_44:after*/
        
        #INPUT_44:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            text-decoration: none solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            column-rule-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            caret-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            border: 0px none rgb(85, 85, 85);
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 15.96px Poppins, sans-serif;
            outline: rgb(85, 85, 85) none 0px;
        }/*#INPUT_44:before*/
        
        #SPAN_45 {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: table-cell;
            height: 38px;
            left: 0px;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 0px;
            perspective-origin: 0px 19px;
            transform-origin: 0px 19px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 0px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#SPAN_45*/
        
        #SPAN_45:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 0px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#SPAN_45:after*/
        
        #SPAN_45:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 0px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#SPAN_45:before*/
        
        #BUTTON_46 {
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            bottom: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            height: 16px;
            left: -36px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            top: 12px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 17px;
            perspective-origin: 8.5px 8px;
            transform-origin: 8.5px 8px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://opencart.templatemela.com/OPC10/OPC100235/OPC4/catalog/view/theme/OPC100235_4/image/megnor/search.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% / auto padding-box border-box;
            border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
            border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px -1px;
            padding: 0px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
        }/*#BUTTON_46*/
        
        #BUTTON_46:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#BUTTON_46:after*/
        
        #BUTTON_46:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 12px / 24px Poppins, sans-serif;
        }/*#BUTTON_46:before*/
```

```html
    <div id="DIV_1" style="padding-right:10%; margin-top:12px; display:inline; overflow:hidden; height:40px; width: 390px">
     <div id="DIV_2"> 
      <div id="DIV_3">
       <div id="DIV_4">
         
        <select name="category_id" id="SELECT_5">
          
         <option value="0" id="OPTION_6">
          All Categories
         </option> 
         <option value="18" id="OPTION_7">
          Fruits
         </option> 
         <option value="20" id="OPTION_8">
          Citrus
         </option> 
         <option value="59" id="OPTION_9">
          oranges
         </option> 
         <option value="61" id="OPTION_10">
          mandarins
         </option> 
         <option value="62" id="OPTION_11">
          limes
         </option> 
         <option value="78" id="OPTION_12">
          Amanatsu
         </option> 
         <option value="79" id="OPTION_13">
          Lemon
         </option> 
         <option value="80" id="OPTION_14">
          Papeda
         </option> 
         <option value="81" id="OPTION_15">
          Grapefruit
         </option> 
         <option value="46" id="OPTION_16">
          Stone fruit
         </option> 
         <option value="63" id="OPTION_17">
          nectarines
         </option> 
         <option value="64" id="OPTION_18">
          apricots
         </option> 
         <option value="65" id="OPTION_19">
          peaches
         </option> 
         <option value="66" id="OPTION_20">
          plums
         </option> 
         <option value="82" id="OPTION_21">
          Peach
         </option> 
         <option value="83" id="OPTION_22">
          Apricot
         </option> 
         <option value="84" id="OPTION_23">
          cherry
         </option> 
         <option value="45" id="OPTION_24">
          Berries
         </option> 
         <option value="67" id="OPTION_25">
          strawberries
         </option> 
         <option value="68" id="OPTION_26">
          raspberries
         </option> 
         <option value="69" id="OPTION_27">
          blueberries
         </option> 
         <option value="70" id="OPTION_28">
          kiwifruit
         </option> 
         <option value="71" id="OPTION_29">
          passionfruit
         </option> 
         <option value="85" id="OPTION_30">
          Cranberries
         </option> 
         <option value="86" id="OPTION_31">
          Bilberries
         </option> 
         <option value="25" id="OPTION_32">
          Fresh Fruits
         </option> 
         <option value="57" id="OPTION_33">
          Beverages
         </option> 
         <option value="17" id="OPTION_34">
          Cookies & Biscuits
         </option> 
         <option value="24" id="OPTION_35">
          Dairy
         </option> 
         <option value="33" id="OPTION_36">
          Exotic Fruits
         </option> 
         <option value="34" id="OPTION_37">
          vegetables
         </option> 
         <option value="72" id="OPTION_38">
          watermelons
         </option> 
         <option value="73" id="OPTION_39">
          apricots
         </option> 
         <option value="74" id="OPTION_40">
          Leafy green
         </option> 
         <option value="75" id="OPTION_41">
          Cruciferous
         </option> 
         <option value="76" id="OPTION_42">
          Marrow
         </option> 
         <option value="77" id="OPTION_43">
          Allium
         </option>
        </select>
       </div>
       <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Product Here..." style="width: 200px" id="INPUT_44" /> <span id="SPAN_45"><button type="submit" id="BUTTON_46">
        </button></span>
      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your search button to submit your form you should not use `<button type="button"></button>` as this presumes you will handle clicks with Javascript.
Simply discard the `type="button"` or set it to `type="submit"` and it will post the `<form>` (which is missing from your code but I asume it's there irl).

Comment: Th4nks it Solved my Problem.

Answer (score -1):

mate as far a I'm aware a select box just allows you to select the item unless you uses jQuery to add functionality but you can achieve a simple search box using datalist. Be sure wrap the datalist in a form element like the example 1. Otherwise link them by using the input list attribute and link to the id of the datalist as in example 2.

example 1:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

example 2:

```html
<datalist id="languages">
   <option value="HTML">
   <option value="CSS">
   <option value="JavaScript">
   <option value="Java">
   <option value="Ruby">
   <option value="PHP">
   <option value="Go">
   <option value="Erlang">
   <option value="Python">
   <option value="C">
   <option value="C#">
   <option value="C++">
</datalist>
<input type="text" list="languages">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="languages" id="languages">
```